# Syntax in R regarding ddply

Tags: r, syntax, plyr

can anyone explain a reason why there would be a period before the `playerID` in the following R statement?

```
dataframe.AB<-ddply(Batting, .(playerID), summarize, Career.AB=sum(AB, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I've seen that argument passed something with the c(...) function...not sure what's going on here.  I should mention that `playerID` is a variable in the `Batting` dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment because it doesn't directly answer your question, but I forsee dplyr overtaking plyr for purposes such as this (due to speed, majorly).  In dplyr, this would be written as Batting %.% group_by(playerId) %.% summarise(Career.AB = sum(AB, na.rm = TRUE)) .

Comment: help(".") is also relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only really necessary if you want to use an expression, such as `.(playerID + 1)`. The `.(` function tells ddply to capture and evaluate the expression in the context of the data (`Batting` in your case). If you just want to group by an unmodified column you can pass that column's name as a character vector (e.g. `"playerID"`, or `c("playerID", "someOtherColumnName")` to group by multiple columns). To expand on my comment, from [Hadley's vignette](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) on plyr (p6-7):

> When operating on a data frame, you usually want to split it up into groups based on combinations of variables in the data set. For d*ply you specify which variables (or functions of variables) to use. These variables are specified in a special way to highlight that they are computed first from the data frame, then the global environment (in which case it is your responsibility to ensure that their length is equal to the number of rows in the data frame).
>
> .(var1) will split the data frame into groups defined by the value of the var1 variable. If you use multiple variables, .(a, b, c), the groups will be formed by the interaction of the variables, and output will be labelled with all three variables...
>
> You can also use functions of variables: .(round(a)), .(a * b). When outputting to a data frame, ugly names (produced by make.names()) may result, but you can override them by specifying names in the call: .(product = a * b).
>
> Alternatively, you can use two more familiar ways of describing the splits:
> As a character vector of column names: c("var1", "var2").